# Set entity record to Active

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

there are plenty of examples out there of how to set a record to Inactive, but how do you set it to Active?

I'm guessing you just use different values for the State and Status option sets, but what are they?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer.

Just replace the state and status values with the correct values from here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb890228.aspx

This code uses a new thread for the process which isn't always necessary, but you get the idea.

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(SetState), (object)new SetStateThreadRequest()
{
    proxy = proxy,
    Request = new SetStateRequest()
    {
        EntityMoniker = new EntityReference(Entity, entity.Id),
        State = new OptionSetValue(0), // <== 0 = Active, 1 = Inactive
        Status = new OptionSetValue(1) // <== 1 = Active, 2 = Inactive (some use -1)
    }
});
```

Comment: To find the correct values for each entity, you can check the StatusMap table in the DB.

Answer (score 1):

Example for activating Account entity:

```
Account account = new Account();

          // ...

          SetStateRequest req = new SetStateRequest();

          req.EntityMoniker = new EntityReference(Account.EntityLogicalName, account.Id);
          req.State = new OptionSetValue(0);
          req.Status = new OptionSetValue(1);

          service.Execute(req);
```

For status and state codes check [Account Entity OptionSet Attribute Metadata on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328014.aspx).